# Creating styles for a ListView in a WPF Desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have some styles for a Metro/win8 app:

```
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF171717" Opacity="0.70"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFEAF32C" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2, 0, 0, 0" />

        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="40" />
    </Style>
```

But now I am making a desktop app in wpf (.net 4.5) and cannot apply styles like this in xaml to a ListView control. How do we define our own custom styles for a Desktop ListView control in xaml?

Comment: you do them exactly like you are doing, is the style not being shown visually at run time or is there an error message? Also, is this style in it's own XAML file? if so you'll need to reference that dictionary

Comment: Well, in Metro apps, the `<style>`'s are placed inside a `<common.LayoutAwarePage.Resources>` but VS is telling me `The namespace prefix "common" is not defined.` I don't know where to put it (I didn't mention this in my question because I just thought it's not a desktop thing)

Comment: Okay, I just looked in my other project and noticed that I may need to define common up the top with xmlns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example putting the style in a windows resource dictionary.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF171717" Opacity="0.70"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFEAF32C" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2, 0, 0, 0" />

            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="40" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView>
                <ListView.Items>
                    <Button>a</Button>
                    <Button>b</Button>
                    <Button>c</Button>
                    <Button>d</Button>
                    <Button>e</Button>
                </ListView.Items>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and if you want the style to be placed in it's own file then you can reference that file like this (my resource file is just call Dictionary1.xaml)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView>
                <ListView.Items>
                    <Button>a</Button>
                    <Button>b</Button>
                    <Button>c</Button>
                    <Button>d</Button>
                    <Button>e</Button>
                </ListView.Items>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: @Andy how do you make it possible to use this with an x:Key reference? I've a nested listview and want the inner one to use this but not the outer one. I've tried a few approaches and can't get it going. The inner ListView.ItemTemplate has a Datatemplate already and can't accept any styling from what I can see - except for child element like Textblock.